# how can i use sqlite rawQuery?

Tags: sqlite, select

when I call select in other function, there is problem in line number 3.
 Is it wrong?

```
public String[] select(int n){
db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM info WHERE number='" + n + "'", null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rawQuery()` looks good, though usually you wouldn't quote integers as `'string literal'`.

However, a non-void method must return a value and your method doesn't return anything. Add `return null;` to make it compile; implement a loop that builds a string array to return a non-null value.